# I've got a Jquery tabs with the tabs set to fixed position. How do I get the tabs to start at the top?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I have a JQuery Tabs problem. I've got tabs set up to be fixed to the top of the page with a lot of content in each of tab's divs. When the content is scrolled through, and another tab is clicked, I need new content to start at the top rather than in the middle somewhere.

Here is an illustration of my problem:
http://hoyu-professional-usa.com/newsite/tabsfix.html

How do I get the words "TAB [x] Start Here!" to appear at the top when the associated tab is clicked?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: could you post your html ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure the best way to do that. How would you like me to post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JS code:

```
$(".ui-tabs-nav li a").click(function() {
    $("body, html").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! Unfortunately, though I've tried adding that code to both the beginning and end of the <body> tags and it's not working for me. What could I be doing wrong in adding it?

Comment: Go in "http://hoyu-professional-usa.com/newsite/tabsfix.html" and in chrome dev tools console tab add my code. And you will see it will scroll top on top nav click

Comment: Yes, I see it works perfectly when I apply it in the chrome dev tools console tab. Unfortunately I still can't figure out how to apply the code to my page directly to make it work. If you have any further insight, please share. In any case thanks for heading me in the right direction!

Comment: For anyone who might happen upon this with a similar problem, I learned to get it edonbajrami's code to work in the file like it does in Chrome Dev Tools was that I needed to wrap the code in an observer:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    [CODE HERE]
  });`

Thanks again!